# Similar angle problem

Tags: geometry

[image]

Can't we use now, *CDE* and *CFB* as similar angle? and then what  next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $ED=BF \cdot \frac{CD}{CF} = AD \cdot \frac{CD}{CD+AB}$.